# R Studio: print output when running interactively but not when knitting

Tags: rstudio

I have a long loop in an rmd notebook. For testing, I've put debug print statements every 1,000 iterations so I can see the loop progress.

I'd like to keep that debug output there while I'm doing my design/testing/debugging but omit that output when knitting my notebook. Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `results="hide"` as a chunk option, as in:

````
```{r results="hide"}
   # r code
```
````